# How to sort an ArrayList by an int in decreasing order?

Tags: java, sorting, int, reverse

I have the following code that sorts my Player class by how good they are rated. There is an `ArrayList` of `Player`s in my `Game` class that I am trying to sort by how high they are rated. Right now, it sorts in opposite order (example after code).

```
// Player class
@Override
public int compareTo(Player o) {
    return(this.getHowGood() > o.getHowGood() ? -1 :
        (this.getHowGood() == o.getHowGood() ? 0 : 1));
}
```

Game class

```
PlayerSorter playerSorter = new PlayerSorter(allCompetitors);
ArrayList<Player> sortedPlayer = playerSorter.getSortedPlayerByHowGood();
System.out.println("-----Sorted JobCandidate by age: Ascending-----");
for(Player player : sortedPlayer) {
    System.out.println(player.getHowGood() + "");
}
```

PlayerSorter class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Collections;   

public class PlayerSorter {

    ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

    public PlayerSorter(ArrayList<Player> player) {
        this.players = player;
    }

    public ArrayList<Player> getSortedPlayerByHowGood() {         
        Collections.sort(players);
        return players;
    }
}
```

What I get in the console (what is on my JFrame):

```
-----Sorted Player by rating: Ascending /*descending is what I'm looking for here*/-----
8
14
22
33
36
42
44
51
52
54
58
60
60
62
65
73
75
84
93
99
```

As I showed above, the numbers are ascending in how good, and I'm trying to make the opposite of that, but can't figure it out. I tried changing the numbers in the `Player` class to their opposite (negative), and that didn't work. I tried reversing the order of the `ArrayList` with `Collections.reverse()` and that didn't work.

Comment: `Collections.sort` need `List` as parameter, not `ArrayList`, so the code do not compile

Comment: An arraylist is a list.  Reverse the inequality sign to lt.

Comment: Okay, I'm not using `Collections.sort`. I'm implementing the `Comparable` class into the Player class.

Comment: First, you DON'T HAVE TO use a ternary expression to return -1, 0, or 1. You could simply do a subtraction between of the two getters--that will give you negative, zero, or positive. Second, reverse the order of the operators in the subtraction to reverse the result of the comparator.

Comment: @RWRkeSBZ thank you, that fixed this. The website I found said to not do that because of errors it **can** throw.

Comment: Operands, not operators.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Collections.sort(players, Collections.reverseOrder())` instead of `Collections.sort(players)`.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the order after sorting:

```
Collections.sort(players);
Collections.reverse(players);
```

or in a single line:

```
Collections.sort(players, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Collections.sort(players);
```

With

```
Collections.sort(players,Collections.<Player>reverseOrder());
```